# unable to scan the vulnerabilities in sonarqube

Tags: security, sonarqube

iam using sonarqube 9.9.3 LTS community version java version 17 and 11 . In this i have make some changes by adding vulnerability into the code but it is not detected.

[this is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CPR1.png) in this the vulnerablity is not detected

Comment: sonarqube is not the right choice in case if you want to detect vulnerabilities in code , try other platforms like Snyk